# Can I determine k with calinski and hrabasz validation when using k-means clustering?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to automatically choose k (k-means clustering) using calinski and harabasz validation from scikit package in python (metrics.calinski_harabaz_score).

I loop through all clustering range to choose the maximum value of calinski_harabaz_score

```
    for kClusterCnt in range(2, 21) :
       value = metrics.calinski_harabaz_score(datasets.data, kmCls.labels_)
```

Is there any defect or mistake when I use only that method?

Comment: You can also roll a dice to choose k. Do not *rely* on these measures, always *verify* your clusters *manually*.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I knew that I have to review the clustering number with sum of squares and other methods. But I need to make a program which automatically choose K and run clustering without human decision. So I wrote the questions to get some advice.

Comment: No, do *not* rely on sum of squares either! Automatic clustering is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to call kmeans fit for every cluster number. I merged example from [scikit learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#calinski-harabaz-index) and your code as below.

```
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
from sklearn import datasets
dataset = datasets.load_iris()
X = dataset.data
y = dataset.target
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=1).fit(X)
labels = kmeans_model.labels_
metrics.calinski_harabaz_score(X, labels)
for k in range(2, 21):
    kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=1).fit(X)
    labels = kmeans_model.labels_
    labels = kmeans_model.labels_
    print k, metrics.calinski_harabaz_score(X, labels)
```

Output is below.

```
2 513.303843352
3 560.399924247
4 529.120719084
5 494.094381914
6 474.517429587
7 448.871449442
8 436.613024881
9 414.530317405
10 390.646480599
11 368.89696343
12 357.194592002
13 342.732084105
14 344.610818724
15 337.809470535
16 324.972019063
17 322.825466107
18 314.587220111
19 306.64863559
20 316.905301605
```

According to this result 3 cluster centers is best. "3 560.399924247".

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Yes, I made source code like you. But I don't know it is effective to choose k and there is no mistakes.

Comment: Finding exact k is still an open research problem. calinski_harabaz_score is one of the proposed methods for cluster fitness. Only you can say if it is effective for your problem/dataset.

Comment: Always do more than one random initialization of k-means.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, k-means is *non-deterministic*, due to the randomness in the initialization phase.  This means you will get a range of answers, and you have to sample that range for every value of k to get the best fit for that k.  It's not one-shot and done.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I try to consider it again.